# How to make autolayout change frame size to maintain constraints on rotation?

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIView` with very simple constraints, as the root view on a `UIViewController`:

[image]

This view has a single subview with all my UI elements in that subview.

Both views have `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO`.  Without this, inconsistent constraints are generated, causing a crash.

When I rotate the device, the location of the view does not move.  It remains the same width as it would be in portrait orientation, and is located on the left of the frame.  Printing the frame in lldb confirms this.

What do I need to add to force the leading/trailing/top/bottom space constraints to apply in both portrait and landscape orientation?

I've tried manually requesting an update, ie:

```
# On the VC
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self.storyView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

but this has not had any effect.

Comment: Your description is a little confusing. Let's give the view a name: you have a rootView and a subView. Presumably, your rootView is the standard empty UIView that the view controller has instantiated. Your subview is where you have all your UI. The subview has its top, bottom, trailing and leading edges pinned to those of the rootView using constraints. In other words: the subView completely fills and covers the rootView. When you rotate the device, the subView does not rotate with the rootView? Is that correct?

Comment: @Maarten - that is correct; in fact, neither view rotates (printing the frame of the default empty view shows that it is still in portrait orientation).